# Accessing a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a function `get_value(dictionary, key)` which returns the value of the given key in the given dictionary.

my code

```
dictionary = {'Sunday':0, 'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2, 'Wednesday':3, 'Thursday':4, 'Friday':5, 'Saturday':6}  
get_value = input("Provide key") 
for day in dictionary:
    if dictionary[day]['key'] == get_value:
        print (day)
```

Comment: Approved. You can proceed.

Comment: I don't see any `get_value` function in your code, what did you tried ?

Comment: `get_value = input("Provide key")`  <== This is a string not a function. Do you want to define a function named `get_value(dict,key)` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a value from dictionary you need to simply use `dictionary[key]`, so in your function you just need to return this value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dictionary = {'Sunday': 0, 'Monday': 1, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Wednesday': 3, 'Thursday': 4, 'Friday': 5, 'Saturday': 6}  

get_value = input("Provide key: ") 

if get_value in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[get_value])
else:
    print('Key not found!')
```

Comment: Or `print(dictionary.get(get_value, 'Key not found!'))`